# Finding number of digits to be changed to get equivalent binary number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The goal is to determine how many digits in the binary number need to be changed to represent the decimal number correctly (either 0 change to 1 or vice versa).

For example: if strArr is ["56", "011000"] then your program should return 1 because only 1 digit needs to change in the binary number (the first zero needs to become a 1) to correctly represent 56 in binary.

`Input: ["5624", "0010111111001"]; Output: 2`

`Input: ["44", "111111"]; Output: 3`

What I have tried so far -

```js
function OffBinary(strArr) { 
  
  let binaryNum = 
    Number(strArr).toString(2).split("").reverse().join("");
  return parseInt(binaryNum + "00", 2); 

}
 
console.log(OffBinary(["5624", "0010111111001"]));
console.log(OffBinary(["44", "111111"]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
function OffBinary(strArr) { 
  let changes = 0;
  Number(strArr[0]).toString(2).split('').forEach((digit, i)=>{
    if (digit != strArr[1].charAt(i)) changes++;         
  });
  return changes;
}
```